# Route53, AWS-CLI : Add Alias A name with aws-cli

Tags: amazon-web-services

I have a requirement, where Kubernetes service is generating an ELB for us with DNS name. I am adding that as an Alias for A, which is giving faster DNS propagation as compared to CNAME. I want to automated adding the entry via shell-script, but it's not working out, I get error as mentioned below. Please note, all e

Error log:

```
An error occurred (InvalidChangeBatch) when calling the ChangeResourceRecordSets operation: [Tried to create an alias that targets dualstack.AXXXXXXXXX-46346364.eu-central-1.elb.amazonaws.com., type A in zone Z0jshgdjhdg, but the alias target name does not lie within the target zone, Tried to create an alias that targets dualstack.asdgdfhgdfh-56767687.eu-central-1.elb.amazonaws.com., type A in zone Z0XXXXX, but that target was not found]
```

Command used:

```
aws route53 change-resource-record-sets --hosted-zone-id /hostedzone/Z0XXXXXXX --change-batch '{"Changes": [ { "Action": "UPSERT", "ResourceRecordSet": { "Name": "test.dev.domain.com", "Type": "A", "AliasTarget":{ "HostedZoneId": "Z0XXXXX","DNSName": "aesdgdfg-46456.eu-central-1.elb.amazonaws.com","EvaluateTargetHealth": false} } } ]}'
```

What am I doing wrong?

Hosted Zone as asked:

[image]

Comment: Can you confirm that you are using `HostedZoneId` of your load balancer, not some other id?

Comment: @Marcin: I can confirm that, I can see the HostedZoneId in route-53, I have also updated the main post to include where I got the hosted Zone ID. Please check bottom of main post. Thank you. :-)

Comment: If you go to Load balancer in the EC2 concole, in `Description` tab of your ELB you will be able to find `Hosted zone` for the balancer. Can you check if this is the same one you are using.

Comment: @Marcin Ur right, it's a different one, but the entry is in the Route53 zone which I have mentioned to u. I also observed, for different VPC's, I have the same hosted-zone, and I don't have access to edit those entries, even though I am an admin. And I am able to edit entries via UI.

Comment: @Marcin : Also, The hosted Zone mentioned in ELB is not present in route-53...i cannot find it. :-)

Comment: In your command, when you set `AliasTarget`, are you using the `HostedZoneId` of the ALB?

Comment: @Marcin : This worked out, So, basically I was required to use 2 Hosted Zone, one which I found in Route53, and other one which I found in ELB side. I dunno why that's the requirement, but okay. Please add an answer, I will accept it. Thanks a lot. :-)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Based on the comments.

The issue was caused by using wrong `HostedZoneId` in `AliasTarget`. The correct one is the `HostedZoneId` associated with your ALB. It can be found in the EC2 console, in `Description` tab of your ALB under `Hosted zone` option.

The command should use two HostedZoneIds:

```
aws route53 change-resource-record-sets \
    --hosted-zone-id /hostedzone/<zone-id-from-route53>\
    --change-batch \
     '{"Changes": [ { "Action": "UPSERT", "ResourceRecordSet": { "Name": "test.dev.domain.com", "Type": "A", "AliasTarget":{ "HostedZoneId": "<zone-id-of-ALB>","DNSName": "aesdgdfg-46456.eu-central-1.elb.amazonaws.com","EvaluateTargetHealth": false} } } ]}'
```

Comment: Please include that we require 2 different hosted zones for this to work, one which is under ELB, and one which is the target Hosted Zone in route53. :-) The first one in command is the one from route53. :-)